# express rest api key auth

Tags: node.js, express, oauth

I want to use a key to authenticate an expressJS REST API. What npm library should I use? I don't want to use username and password.

Basically, I will generate a random key and issue this key to the client for API access.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use passportjs for authentication middleware, and for using a token/key to authenticate you can use for example Bearer to add the token/key in the petition headers. You can fin here and example [bearer](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-http-bearer-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party authentication providers to avoid taking username and password as input. Use Google, Facebook authentication using PassportJS
Here is the link to Passport supporting third party authentication providers:

http://www.passportjs.org/packages/

Comment: The link is dead